# Minimum number of meetings so that each researcher has met every other researcher

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are $n \ge 4$ math researchers at the Indian institute of Mathematics. The institute being a strong patron of collaborations organizes a series of coffee meetings between researchers wherein the researchers share whatever knowledge of mathematics they have and might have
received from other researchers during their previous meetings.

a) Prove that the minimum number of meetings that need to be arranged in order to ensure that each researcher has the knowledge of everyone else's in the department is at most $2n-4$.

b)Prove that the minimum number required above cannot be less than $2n-4$, and hence conclude that $2n-4$ is exactly the minimum number of required meetings.

Sorry, I am clueless about this question and am unable to express my views. Will translating this question into a graph will help?

Comment: I assume that "coee meetings" were coffee meetings, but you were so excited to copy and paste your homework for us that you didn't check?

Comment: Yes it is coffee and i am sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: I think you need to state that meetings happen 1 to 1? Also "and might have received from other researchers during their previous meetings" is a good hint.

Comment: There are lots of things you can try before just coming here to say please solve this problem for me. Have you looked at small examples? Do you have guesses about how to generalize? Have you done similar problems in class or read similar problems in a textbook? Can you prove any weaker results (even much weaker)?